# Azure DBFS file structure does not exist Python DataFrame to file storage

Tags: python, pandas, csv, databricks

I have created a pandas dataframe called 'entity'. I am trying to store this in databricks file store.

I created a directory within the FileStore with this command:
`dbutils.fs.mkdirs('dbfs:/FileStore/NER/')`
I know that this exists because I can see it in the FileStore and copy its path (see image)
When I try to write my dataframe to a CSV, using
`entity.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/NER/entity.csv', header=True, index=False)` or
`entity.to_csv('/dbfs:/FileStore/NER/entity.csv', header=True, index=False)` or
`entity.to_csv('FileStore/NER/entity.csv', header=True, index=False)`
I get the following error
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/NER' or similar. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I can see the directory
[image: Image of DBFS file structure showing FileStore/NER]

Comment: Are you on community edition?

Comment: Hmm. No I'm not, why though?

Comment: Are you using shared cluster? I've asked about community edition because `/dbfs` doesn't work there